# JTextField in a JFrame is taking too much space outside the actual text field

Tags: java, jframe, components

Ok so I'm creating a Menu/GUI for a program I am working on but I don't have too much experience with this so I need some help with the component organization and the layout.

Right now, when I run this code, as you can see in the picture (sorry I don't have enough rep to embed it, new to stackoverflow) there Is a large space between The JTextField and the where the previous buttons / window border is. It would be great if someone could help me fix this. :)
Thanks.

[image: Layout]

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class WindowWin extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JPanel[] row = new JPanel[4];
JButton[] button = new JButton[4];  
String[] buttonString = {"Copy to Clipboard","Go","Back","Info"};

int[] dimW = {400,200,65};
int[] dimH = {40,100};

Dimension keyDim = new Dimension(dimW[0],dimH[0]);
Dimension displayDimension = new Dimension(dimW[0],dimH[1]);
Dimension butDim = new Dimension(dimW[1],dimH[0]);
Dimension infoDim = new Dimension(dimW[2],dimH[0]);

JEditorPane display = new JEditorPane();
Font font = new Font("Times new Roman",Font.PLAIN, 14);

JTextField keyIn = new JTextField(24);
JEditorPane msgIn = new JEditorPane();

JScrollPane scrollerD = new JScrollPane(display,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
JScrollPane scrollerM = new JScrollPane(msgIn,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    WindowWin c = new WindowWin();
}

WindowWin(){
    super("Test");

//  setDesign();
    //setSize(380,250);
    setSize(460,500);

    setResizable(true);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(4,3);

    setLayout(grid);

    FlowLayout f1 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);
    FlowLayout f2 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,1,1);
    //FlowLayout South

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        row[i] = new JPanel();

    row[0].setLayout(f1);

    for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        row[i].setLayout(f2);

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        button[i] = new JButton();
        button[i].setText(buttonString[i]);
        button[i].setFont(font);
        button[i].addActionListener(this);
    }

    display.setFont(font);
    display.setEditable(false);
    display.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    display.setPreferredSize(displayDimension);

    keyIn.setFont(font);
    keyIn.setEditable(true);
    keyIn.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    keyIn.setPreferredSize(keyDim);

    msgIn.setFont(font);
    msgIn.setEditable(true);
    msgIn.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    msgIn.setPreferredSize(displayDimension);


    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    button[i].setPreferredSize(butDim);
    for(int i = 2; i < 4; i++)
    button[i].setPreferredSize(infoDim);

    row[0].add(scrollerD);
    add(row[0]);

    row[1].add(scrollerM);
    add(row[1]);


    row[2].add(button[0]);
    row[2].add(button[1]);
    add(row[2]);

    row[3].add(button[2]);
    row[3].add(keyIn);
    row[3].add(button[3]);
    add(row[3]);

    setVisible(true);

}

/*  public final void setDesign()
    {
        try
        {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
*/  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

         if(ae.getSource() == button[0])
         {


         }

         if(ae.getSource() == button[1])
         {
             display.setText("Test");
         }
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        try
        {
            display.setText("");
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
        }
    }

    public void outd()
    {
        display.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: your code looks a bit messed up but i'll clean it a bit for you

Comment: That's how `GridLayout` works...

Answer (score 0):

The gab between 1 row and the other can be adjusted by using the GridLayout(int rows, int cols, int hgap, int vgap) constructor.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html for more information about gridlayout can be found here.

Answer (score 0):

This is how `GridLayout` works, each cell is given exactly the same amount of the space.  Instead, try using something like `GridBagLayout`...

```
GridBagLayout grid = new GridBagLayout();
setLayout(grid);
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

//...

row[0].add(scrollerD);
add(row[0], gbc);

row[1].add(scrollerM);
add(row[1], gbc);

row[2].add(button[0]);
row[2].add(button[1]);
add(row[2], gbc);

row[3].add(button[2]);
row[3].add(keyIn);
row[3].add(button[3]);
add(row[3], gbc);
```

[image: Layout]

```
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class WindowWin extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JPanel[] row = new JPanel[4];
    JButton[] button = new JButton[4];
    String[] buttonString = {"Copy to Clipboard", "Go", "Back", "Info"};

    int[] dimW = {400, 200, 65};
    int[] dimH = {40, 100};

    Dimension keyDim = new Dimension(dimW[0], dimH[0]);
    Dimension displayDimension = new Dimension(dimW[0], dimH[1]);
    Dimension butDim = new Dimension(dimW[1], dimH[0]);
    Dimension infoDim = new Dimension(dimW[2], dimH[0]);

    JEditorPane display = new JEditorPane();
    Font font = new Font("Times new Roman", Font.PLAIN, 14);

    JTextField keyIn = new JTextField(24);
    JEditorPane msgIn = new JEditorPane();

    JScrollPane scrollerD = new JScrollPane(display, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    JScrollPane scrollerM = new JScrollPane(msgIn, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                WindowWin c = new WindowWin();
            }
        });
    }

    WindowWin() {
        super("Test");

//  setDesign();
        //setSize(380,250);
//        setSize(460, 500);

//        setResizable(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(4, 3);
        GridBagLayout grid = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout(grid);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        FlowLayout f1 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);
        FlowLayout f2 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 1, 1);
        //FlowLayout South

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            row[i] = new JPanel();
        }

        row[0].setLayout(f1);

        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            row[i].setLayout(f2);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            button[i] = new JButton();
            button[i].setText(buttonString[i]);
            button[i].setFont(font);
            button[i].addActionListener(this);
        }

        display.setFont(font);
        display.setEditable(false);
        display.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        display.setPreferredSize(displayDimension);

        keyIn.setFont(font);
        keyIn.setEditable(true);
        keyIn.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        keyIn.setPreferredSize(keyDim);

        msgIn.setFont(font);
        msgIn.setEditable(true);
        msgIn.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        msgIn.setPreferredSize(displayDimension);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            button[i].setPreferredSize(butDim);
        }
        for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++) {
            button[i].setPreferredSize(infoDim);
        }

        row[0].add(scrollerD);
        add(row[0], gbc);

        row[1].add(scrollerM);
        add(row[1], gbc);

        row[2].add(button[0]);
        row[2].add(button[1]);
        add(row[2], gbc);

        row[3].add(button[2]);
        row[3].add(keyIn);
        row[3].add(button[3]);
        add(row[3], gbc);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    /*  public final void setDesign()
     {
     try
     {
     UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
     "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
     }
     }
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        if (ae.getSource() == button[0]) {

        }

        if (ae.getSource() == button[1]) {
            display.setText("Test");
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        try {
            display.setText("");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }
    }

    public void outd() {
        display.setText("");
    }
}
```

You should also use `pack` over `setSize`, this will take into account the different frame borders that each look and feel/platform might have and uses the layout manager API which does a better job and taking into rendering differences between platforms...

You might like to take a look at:

- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

...for more details